# Xcode 4 - Connecting Outlets

Tags: iphone, xcode, connection, iboutlet, xcode4

This page shows how easily I can connect outlets http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html in Xcode 4, but I can't get it.

I right click and drag an outlet from the new referencing outlet circle, and into my header where the object is declared, but nothing happens.

Has anyone used this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 29):

I had the same problem with the final version of Xcode 4 and solved it by selecting the *File's Owner Custom Class* before using the drag & drop outlet feature like shown on the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have been looking for this since yesterday... thank god for you. Why has it changed for no reason at all?

Comment: @Martin - what did you use to place the numbers and arrows on that image? I use Pixen for my MSPaint like needs, but Pixen is woefully inadequate.

Answer (score 0):

Also, fyi, for outlets the item has to be on a window, not just on the background.  It will connect fine, but it will not process the outlet gesture.  ort11

Answer (score 0):

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3054574?start=0&tstart=0

this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was dragging the outlet from "Outlets/delegate", but it must come from "Referencing outlets".