# How to connect UISwitch with outlet

Tags: ios, user-interface, storyboard

I need to connect my `UISwitch` outlet with it's outlet in connections inspector. But when I do it I see a big lock. I checked `Custom Class` - all is right. What is the problem?

P.S. What I do: [image: What I did]

And I tried this: [Xcode 4 - Connecting Outlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346350/xcode-4-connecting-outlets) but it doesn't help.

Comment: How is `personSwitchControl` declared in code?

Comment: Yes, it is. `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *parentSwichControl;`

Comment: OK, what happens if either. 1. You drag from the yellow circle (below the VC) to the switch. 2. Open the assistant editor and drag from the switch to the line in the code.

Comment: In all situations I see the lock

Comment: Hmm... can you get a screenshot of this lock. I've never seen it before.

Comment: Try right-clicking on the switch and drag from the New Referencing Outlet to the View Controller under the View Controller Scene (to the left of the storyboard).

Comment: Yes, I show you video

Comment: Code Monkey, I see the lock(

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PqWklsIIVws&feature=youtube_gdata_player

Comment: I even can't add smth to this storyboard